# Filtering data containing numeric values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter, qgis-expression, numeric

My dataset contains numeric values, alphanumeric values, and non-numeric values. How can I filter data which contains numeric values? Below is an example showing a list of data and filtered data which I want.

[image]

Comment: Is the criteria for matching as simple as, "if a text field contains at least 1 number character then return the whole field?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following expression with function [`regexp_match()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches). The Regular Expression `\\d` finds [any digit](https://regexone.com/lesson/letters_and_digits). Use double backslashes, because in QGIS,

> [Backslash characters must be double escaped](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-match)

```
regexp_match ("Data",('\\d'))
```

[image]